# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to execute sql queries in a independent class , Below is my code.I have referred some links and I have added jdbc-oracle jar and ojdbc14 jars as shown in the image, I have added the path in the environment variables . But I am not able to connect or execute queries

```
    package com.infomatics.orion.dao.impl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class EntityTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EntityTest c1 = new EntityTest();
        c1.test();
    }
    private void test(){
         Connection con = null;
           try {
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                con = DriverManager.
                         getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:3306:orion_db"
                             ,"root","orion123");
                  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}

}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXOtM.png): [image]

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at com.infomatics.orion.dao.impl.EntityTest.test(EntityTest.java:23)
at com.infomatics.orion.dao.impl.EntityTest.main(EntityTest.java:15)
```

This is the exception I am getting after doing the above things.

Comment: Which Oracle version is your database? `ojdbc14` is a really old driver (for Java 1.4); which exact driver version is this?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I am using MYSQL server 5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the Oracle JDBC driver to connect to a MySQL database.

I get exactly that error attempting to connect to MySQL 5.7 using ojdbc14.

You need to use the [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) library instead of `ojdbc`.  Your connection URL should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orion_db` instead of `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:3306:orion_db`.