# cannot connect an android appplication to oracle database using jcdb

Tags: android, mobile

i tired to connect my android and databse using jdbc but i get the eror  java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch and i already jar file into libary [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi8ti.png)
i think it should connect to databse being able to display database

`package com.example.tryconnectdatabase;`

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.os.StrictMode;`
`import android.util.Log;`
`import android.view.View;`
`import android.widget.TextView;`
`import android.widget.Toast;`

`import java.sql.Connection;`
`import java.sql.DriverManager;`
`import java.sql.ResultSet;`
`import java.sql.Statement;`

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
private TextView textView;

private static final String DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myipaddress:1521:XE";

private static final String port = "1521";
private static final String USERNAME = "mars72";
private static final String PASSWORD = "mars72";

private String debug = "";

private Connection connection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy threadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicy);
}

public void buttonConnectToOracleDB(View view) {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select count(*)" +
                "from tms_full_report a where staff_id = '081049' and in_stat = 'Late IN' and " +
                "a.day_mm = to_char(sysdate,'MM') and " +
                "a.day_yyyy = to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')" +
                "  order by department_name,  staff_name, day_date");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            stringBuffer.append(resultSet.getString(1) + "\n");
        }
        textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        textView.setText(e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        debug = e.toString();
        Log.v("debug=", debug);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004) and [don't use images for errors/logs/code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/295004).

Comment: i got this eror java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate: [java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46716722/295004)

Comment: already test it but the result is still the same.

Comment: Edit your post to include details of what type of database (Oracle, MySQL, Postgress) you are connected to running on which OS version (Windows/Linux/Mac) and explain why don't you use a webservice. Do realize that Android != Java SE so recent JARs may not work.